# How to fix validation of optional fields using Switch component (material-ui) with Formik

Tags: material-ui, react-hooks, formik

I'm trying to fix a bug in a form. The form is built with Formik and a custom react component called GenericForm which basically handles the validation and maps an array of objects into the form sub-component renders.

```
const advancedFields = [
        {
            label: "Power Factor",
            id: "powerFactor",
            type: "number",
            value: "",
            isRequired: useAdvancedOptions,
        },
        {
            label: "Efficiency",
            id: "efficiency",
            type: "number",
            value: "",
            isRequired: useAdvancedOptions,
        },
    ];
```

The variable useAdvancedOptions is part of the component state, updated with the new react hook and a Switch component.

```
<FormControlLabel control={ <Switch onChange={
         () => setUseAdvancedOptions(!useAdvancedOptions)
}color={"primary"}/>}label="Advanced Options"/>
```

So the bug... when I toggle advancedOptions on and off with the switch, if the field has been touched, the submit button won't validate if there are no values inside the two advanced fields, even when the fields have been excluded from the form.

When I use Chrome debugger and inspect the variable useAdvancedOptions inside the field objects, it appears that the boolean values for isRequired are updating as anticipated, so I'm not sure why the button is still trying to require the field.

Comment: This behavior from Formik seems to be responsible https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1173

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation was broken, when it would read one of the values that existed in formic and filter it, the iteration that was taking the removed advanced option value would take null into the switch case and fail. I wrote a conditional to return before the switch statement if the iteration filter resulted in null.